Why does caching/memoization in a sorting comparator increase runtime instead of reducing it?
I'm solving a problem on Leetcode where I need to sort an array of integers based on their mapped values using a custom digit mapping. I’ve implemented two versions of the solution to address this problem:

Without Caching: This implementation directly computes the mapped value for each comparison during sorting.
With Caching: This version uses a cache (hash/unordered_map) to store previously computed mapped values to avoid redundant calculations.

Here are my submissions:
Submission 1: Without caching
class Solution {
    // Brute Force Solution: Convert each number into its mapped number and then compare both
public:
    static vector<int> sortJumbled(vector<int> &mapping, vector<int> &nums) {
        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [&mapping](int a, int b) {
            int mappedA = _getMappedNum(mapping, a);
            int mappedB = _getMappedNum(mapping, b);

            if (mappedA == mappedB) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return mappedB > mappedA;
            }
        });

        return nums;
    }

private:
    static int _getMappedNum(const vector<int> &mapping, int num) {
        if(num == 0)
            return mapping[0];

        int ans = 0;
        int power = 1;
        while (num != 0) {
            int digit = num % 10;
            int mappedDigit = mapping[digit];
            ans += power * mappedDigit;

            num /= 10;
            power *= 10;
        }

        return ans;
    }
};

Submission 2: With caching
class Solution {
public:
    static vector<int> sortJumbled(vector<int> &mapping, vector<int> &nums) {
        unordered_map<int, int> dp;

        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [&mapping, &dp](int a, int b) {
            int mappedA = _getMappedNum(mapping, dp, a);
            int mappedB = _getMappedNum(mapping, dp, b);

            if (mappedA == mappedB) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return mappedB > mappedA;
            }
        });

        return nums;
    }

private:
    static int _getMappedNum(const vector<int> &mapping, unordered_map<int, int> &dp, int num) {
        if (dp.find(num) != dp.end()) {
            return dp[num];
        }
        if (num == 0)
            return mapping[0];

        int originalNum = num;
        int ans = 0;
        int power = 1;

        while (num != 0) {
            int digit = num % 10;
            int mappedDigit = mapping[digit];
            ans += power * mappedDigit;

            num /= 10;
            power *= 10;
        }

        dp[originalNum] = ans;
        return ans;
    }
};

Issue:
I observed that the runtime of the cached version (Submission 2) is worse (800ms) than the non-cached version (Submission 1)(400ms) on Leetcode. Although the memorization approach was intended to improve performance, the result is counterintuitive. I’ve verified with a debugger that cached values are being correctly utilized, so the problem is not with the caching logic itself.
Question:
Why does the Leetcode's runtime which in turn is deduced from the code's time complexities increase in the solution with caching from 400ms to 800ms? Could the use of caching in the comparator with std::sort lead to unexpected performance issues, or is there another potential problem in my implementation? I’m looking for insights into why caching might not provide the expected performance benefits.

Your submission links don't work. Include the code in the question.

Also, the problem has absolutely nothing to do with dynamic programming.

Sounds like a leetcode problem to me (algorithm issue) not a C++ one.  I really thing you should ask this on leetcode forums not here.. Here you should show your code as part of the question (not links to it). And then provide debugging details

Also if you're serious about learning C++, learn C++ first (e.g. learncpp.com) and do competitive coding later (you will only pickpu bad habits you have to unlearn later, and which will look very bad in job interviews too)

@PepijnKramer I indeed have spent a lot of time studying C++ for a bit now which is why this is even more confusing. Memorization should improve the time complexity, instead of decreasing it.

Does leetcode give even a tenth of a  about time complexity or is purely concerned with raw elapsed time? It's pretty easy to write low time complexity code that's insanely slow. Nothing keeps an O(1) algorithm from taking 13.5 billion years.

@user4581301 It is "measuring" elapsed time. But it cannot even measure raw elapsed time accurately or consistently. The system is being used by a lot of other users, so sometimes it is slow (CPU load), or you get extra cache misses. All in all it's just a scam

@OP to be honest your C++ code looks better than most competitive code I've seen (but I couldn't tell because the initial links didn't show any code)

I get the issue with LeetCode's and its ability to time problems, but could someone please consider looking at the underlying problem instead of downvoting the question? I'm still trying to understand if it's truly a bad question to ask because I was seriously stuck thinking.

"Why does the time complexity increase in the solution with caching?" What exactly makes you think this? How do you think the time complexity increases? From what complexity to what complexity? Why are you so sure, that the time complexity isn't reduced? "I observed that the time complexity of the cached version (Submission 2) is worse than the non-cached version (Submission 1)" How?

Hey @jabaa, sorry if I wasn't clear before. I think the time complexity is O(mnlogn) initially, but after caching, it should improve towards O(n log n). However, when I checked the runtime on LeetCode, the memoized solution consistently took twice as long as the non-memoized solution (800ms vs 400ms).

If it's exactly twice, it seems like they have the same time complexity. What makes you think, that they have different time complexities? Remember: O(2*n) == O(n)

I get it, they may have same time complexities, but runtime should anyway reduce, considering we won't have to compute mapping over and over again.

You asked, why the question was downvoted. One reason could be the wrong assumption in the title and the description. The next point is: if you want to compare performance, use compiler optimization. Don't compare unoptimized builds. Unoptimized debug builds can have very surprising performance.

Edited the question for better clarity, but any idea about the increased runtime?

If you want to compare performance, use compiler optimization. Don't compare unoptimized builds. Unoptimized debug builds can have very surprising performance. Additional caching and memoization has overhead. That could be a reason for worse performance in very small examples. Use a profiler to analyze the codes.

What I would do: 1) Make a very long and abusive input set that will take a long time to process. 2) run non-memoized  code under profiler and input the input set from 1 to get a good baseline. Store the profiler output. 3) Run memoized code under profiler and feed in the input set from 1. Compare profiler output with baseline to see where the pig is. Note running 2-3 several times can help to smooth out jitter.

If the above doesn't answer your question, 4) edit question and add the major profiler run differences to the question so we can help interpret.

I want to echo @user4581301's post. Our intuition about where CPU time is being spent at runtime can be surprisingly faulty. Use a profiler to know where the hotspots are.

You're making multiple lookups into the map in the cached version each time you call the function, which won't help your run time. find returns an iterator, use it to grab the value if it's found. dp[originalNum] = ans does a look up, creates the value, then updates the value. Just use emplace


I’m looking for insights into why caching might not provide the expected performance benefits.

Well, the worst possible case for memoization (or any sort of cache) is: no hits, all misses.
In that case you're doing a bunch of extra work for zero (or net negative) benefit.
If you're writing tests or benchmarks for a sorting algorithm, you should be including all the degenerate cases, such as:

empty input
all the input values are the same
all the input values are different
the input is in exactly the same order as the desired output
the input is in exactly the reverse order to the desired output
anything else you can think of to trip up pivot selection (smallest/largest right in the middle, etc.)

It's reasonable to suspect that an online competition would use some of the same test cases you would normally use locally, and you can see that one of those cases will be slower with memoization than without.

NB. The fact that the memoized version will frequently be faster on real-world workloads (at least once you fix the double-lookup) is one of the many problems with using leetcode and similar competition sites for learning.
